# what is the “%1$d” output meaning?

Tags: c, ubuntu

im using ubuntu to run this code. but what does the code mean?

running ubuntu code:
gcc name.c -o name

/name

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
  printf("%d %1$d %2$d",5);
}
```

the output is "5 5 random number ". So, what meaning of %2$d?

Answer (score 3):

The `1$` and `2$` specifies the position of the argument. It's only specified by POSIX, it is not in C standard.

According to the C standard the behavior of `printf` here is undefined anyway, as the `$` is not a valid `printf` conversion specification.

According to [fprintf posix](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fprintf.html):

> [...] In format strings containing the "%n$" form of a conversion
>   specification, a field width or precision may be indicated by the
>   sequence "*m$", where m is a decimal integer in the range
>   [1,{NL_ARGMAX}] giving the position in the argument list (after the
>   format argument) of an integer argument containing the field width or
>   precision, for example:
>
> printf("%1$d:%2$.*3$d:%4$.*3$d\n", hour, min, precision, sec);

So:

```
printf("%d %1$d %2$d",5);
```

- `%d` - specifies that the next *int* argument should be converted to a signed decimal.
- `%1$d` - specifies that the *first* after format string *int* argument should be converted to a signed decimal
- `%2$d` - specifies that the *second* after format string *int* argument should be converted to a signed decimal

You gave only two arguments to the `printf` function (the format string and `5`). The result is undefined, because `2$` expects another argument.

Comment: Is this possible to use half-writes (%hn) to accurately control arbitrary DWORDS in memory?

Comment: it's find in this website https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/134.html example 3.

Comment: What is a "half-write"? I don't understand your question. The `%hn` is a printf conversion specifier that expects short argument in comparision to `%n` which expects int. The `%n` is considered dangerous, like, everywhere. It is probably meant, that the attacker can manipulate the `printf` format and change `%n` into `%hn` and can use this to break things. Anyway, the link you posted, is about `Use of Externally-Controlled Format String` - this is as dangerous as it sounds.

Comment: do u have any example of this? why this so dangerous?

Comment: No? Why would I? Consider the first example on that site. Consider I call the program with `./program "123%hn"` I can put `3` into the stack. By manipulating the string I can actually put any number into the stack, `blabla%hhu` will put 6. By manipulating the stack around the program, I can put whatever I want onto the programs stack, overwriting it's memory. In security programs (like those that check passwords) it could be possible to overwrite internal memory of the program and elevate permissions (like, by setting `bool is_password_ok = true` from inside the program).